# JavaScript: Need input element to change options based on entered data

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I have a page, where I need to filter through all kinds of data (served as JSON variable) using just pure javascript. Everything works nicely until I try to implement a datalist where the contents of that list are updated in realtime, based on user input.

```js
var data = [{name:"Paul"},{name:"Alex"},{name:"Laura"}]  // This is just example object

function updateSearch() {
  let search = document.getElementById('search').value;
  let options = document.getElementById('searchList');
  options.innerHTML = "";
  if (search.length >= 2) {
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    for (let d of data) {
      if (d.name.toLowerCase().search(search) === 0) {
        options.innerHTML += `
                        <option>${d.name}</option>
                    `;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<datalist id='searchList'></datalist>
<input type="search" id="search" list='searchList' onchange="updateSearch()">
```

The goal is to not show the full list of names until at least 2 characters are entered, but it just won't update until the user clicks out focuses back to search input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to achieve what you require would be to replace the event type that `updateSearch()` is bound to from `onchange` to `onkeyup`:

```js
const data = [
{ name : "Foo" },
{ name : "Bar" },
{ name : "Bing" },
{ name : "Bong" },
{ name : "Boo!" }];

function updateSearch() {
  let search = document.getElementById('search').value;
  let options = document.getElementById('searchList');

  options.innerHTML = "";
  if (search.length >= 2) {
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    for (let d of data) {
      if (d.name.toLowerCase().search(search) === 0) {
        options.innerHTML += `
                        <option>${d.name}</option>
                    `;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<datalist id='searchList'></datalist>
<!-- Update to onkeyup -->
<input type="search" id="search" list='searchList' onkeyup="updateSearch()">
```

Doing this will cause the `datalist` to interactivly update as the user types. Hope that helps!